# Retrieve affiliations from research paper

Tags: data-request, tool-request, research

I am trying to download the data of the research papers published by people in my university. What I would like to do is then to plot the geographical distribution of the authors, and see how it evolves as a function of time.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do this, in case it can be done? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have already have a list of papers, or is that what you are trying to collect? I think via a university, the tools from Thompson-Reuters or similar should have indexed affiliation.

Comment: I am trying to download data relative to all papers published by my university. I need only two types of information: the year of the paper and the location of the various contributors. Web of Science by Thomson Reuters let you download data for 10 articles at a time, with no information on the author locations. Did anybody try mining Google Scholar with scholar.py (http://www.icir.org/christian/scholar.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the bibliographic databases offer APIs, but they might not be 100% open.  Typically, you can't get access to the ones that charge for access unless your institution has a subscription to the service.

I know that link-only answers are bad, but the problem is that policies change over time, and the folks at MIT libraries has a rather long list of bibiometric APIs and info about how open they are, which I assume they'd maintain/update over time:

- http://libguides.mit.edu/apis

For your purposes, I'd avoid the subject specific ones (pubmed, arXiv) or publisher specific ones, and look to [JSTOR Data for Research](http://about.jstor.org/service/data-for-research) or [Web of Science](http://isiwebofknowledge.com/products_tools/products/related/webservices/) (the one run by Thomspon-Reuters).

As you're interested in tracking by people, I'd like to recommend [ORCID](http://support.orcid.org/knowledgebase/topics/19247-rest-api), but it requires your faculty registering with them and acknowledging their papers, so they don't mis-attribute papers because of similar names.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote to the people at JSTOR asking if they could send me the data I'm looking for (on their website, the maximum number of results per search is 1000).